# How do I change the version of Ubuntu in Google Colab?

Tags: ubuntu, version, google-colaboratory, upgrade

When I run Google Colab I have Ubuntu 18.04 version there - bionic
But I need to work with program that only support Ubuntu version 21.04 - hirsute
It takes a very long time to update / upgrade / tmp /.
How can I quickly change to a new version?

Comment: > It takes a very long time to update

: Can you share how do you update? I'd like to know even if it takes time.